# Dynamic-Link Library .Net ignore reference Path

Tags: dll, dll-reference

Hi everyone i'm having some problems with Dlls for some reason in run time, Dynamic-Link Library is loading wrong library and this is breaking my dependencies:

Reference in Reference Manager:

[image]

Reference in dynamic loader:
[image]

Anyone can help me?